# Hibernate Select. Return Object without selecting everything

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Im not sure if the title is clear, but I am going to expose my problem.
I have an object with more fields than the ones I can obtain from the table it is mapped.
So, how can I return an object, setting the others fields to NULL¿?
Look an example:

This is my class User:

```
package org.arpit.javapostsforlearning;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity(name="User_table")
public class User {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    int userId;

    String userName;

    String userMessage;

//    public User(String userName, String userMessage)
//      {
//          this.userName= userName;
//          this.userMessage = userMessage;
//      }
//  public User(){}

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getUserMessage() {
        return userMessage;
    }
    public void setUserMessage(String userMessage) {
        this.userMessage = userMessage;
    }

}
```

And I want to obtain an object, setting the field userMessage to null or whatever, because I cannot obtain this from my table.
I have tried Select userId userName from User_table; but no success, any idea¿?
Changing the Object with other fields is not an option cause I would have to change too much.

This is my code:

```
public User buscaHotel(int id){

    User user = new User();
    SessionFactory sf = open();
    Session ss=sf.openSession();
    ss.beginTransaction();      
    Query query = ss.createQuery("select userId, userName from User_table where userId = :id ");
    query.setParameter("id", id);
    List<User> list = query.list();
    if (list.size() != 0){
        System.out.println("Not NULL");
    user = list.get(0);
    ss.getTransaction().commit();
    ss.close();
    return user;
    }
    else {
    ss.getTransaction().commit();
    ss.close();
    return user;
    }
}
```

I don't know if I made myself clear....
This is what happens when I try to do what I am trying:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to org.arpit.javapostsforlearning.User
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is not an HQL but a native SQL -

```
select userId, userName from User_table where userId = :id
```

And it gives you a list of `Object[]`, array of objects, and not a list of `User`s. So, you need to change the following -

```
List<User> list = query.list();
```

to

```
List<Object[]> list = query.list();
```

And also change the following

```
user = list.get(0);
```

to

```
Object[] row = list.get(0);
```

Now, immediately after the above line, you can populate the `User` object that you instantiated at the beginning as follows -

```
user.setUserId((Integer)row[0]);
user.setUserName((String)row[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much really, it solved the problem perfectly, it was driving me crazy trying to do this. By the way, do you know any good book that explain that kind of things¿? Cause I really haven't find anything usefull for solving my problem if not, it doesn't matter, you have done more than enough, thanks =)!

Answer (score 0):

If your table does not contain a column corresponding to an entity field, you should mark this field with `transient` modifier (or `@Transient` annotation). It is then excluded from mapping for good. If your table has nullable columns, they are perfectly valid mapping targets.

Your exception however has no relation to that. You should load your entities with `session.get(...)` or `session.load(...)`, hibernate criteria or the like, which all accept your entity class (`User.class`) as a parameter. Your query does not know that you want a `User` entity.